# Streaming Android-recorded video online

Tags: android, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm working on a project for courier service. I have developed an Android Application for our employees wich works as a camera app, they can make photos and video records with. When the photo or video file is ready, this app can automatically upload it to the server (if WiFi connection is active). The server maintains a web site where we can see each employee's daily job, including links to photo and video files. Of course, there is no problem accessing photos through any browser, but there is such problem with video files.

We don't restrict Android devices with which an employee works, only that it is powered by Android 2.3.3 or later (and certainly must have a camera). Video is written with CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW setting, so it's format is up to device's decision what this CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW is. There is no problem in viewing video files from varying devices on a desktop (Windows). Me and my chief have some browser plugins so this files can be open in a browser. But we want to have a video viewing solution on site that does not require any browser plugin or additional software at the client's side.

So the questions are:

1. What is the best video format that can enable online video viewing without downloading the whole file to the client's side (like at YouTube), video records can be very long (an hour, two hours or even more).
2. What tool I need for a universal conversion of Android-recorded video files to that format, without manually specifying input file format (as it can be quite different)? Our server is powered by "`SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u1 x86_64"`.

I may have missed something. I'm sorry, this is my first project to deal with video, I lack knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question, as it all seems decided already. After further research I came to decision that we will stream everything at our site with  tag, the only source will be .mp4 (H.264), as we thought that 99.9% of our users will have no problem with it. I'a a windows user, and I have no problem with watching H.264 video in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft Internet Explorer, and so most of our clients will do.

As for video conversion into H.264, **ffmpeg** will do the job. I have already done some tests, all great. The real problem was to manage video rotation, as all video is recorded from Android phones in portrait mode, and it appeared that at Android this is done by recording frames in landscape mode (native camera orientation), but specifying 90 degree rotation attribute in meta data. And a great quantity of video players and Firefox refused to understand it. The problem can be solved by "transpose" and "rotate" in a command like this:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.avi -vf "transpose=1" -r 25 -b:a 64k -b:v 256k -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 r1.mp4
```

- `-vf "transpose=1"` physically rotates frames 90 degrees
- `-metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0` clears rotation attribute in meta data because rotation is already done

Left is the job to tune parameters for output quality, write a batch conversion script, put it on crontab, and write HTML and JS to allow people to watch this video.